# Using specs2 play! fake application with Reactivemongo causes timeouts

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.1, specs2, reactivemongo

We are currently working on an issue where we use specs2 in scala togeather with mongodb/reactivemongo + Play!.

When we run the tests that write to mongodb the first operation runs fine the all subsequent tests/writes fail due to a timeout when to mongodb.

We found what seems to be an already documented bug on the reactive mongo site here:
https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo/issues/32

Does anyone know a workaround for this issue?

We have already tried:

- Forcing the tests to be run in sequence
- Each test running in its own fake application
- Running all tests in the same fake application
- Defining the collection as a def (as suggested in the issue 32 above)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may find interest in http://acolyte.eu.org/reactive-mongo.html

Answer (score 1):

You can change (in your Controller/Repo/DAO/Service or whatever you call it):

```
val db = ReactiveMongoPlugin.db
```

to

```
def db = ReactiveMongoPlugin.db
```

Meaning val to **def**

Problem occures because calling

```
play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoPlugin#db
```

returns current database setup so making it *val* wires it to the first test.

FYI before each test *Reactive Mongo Plugin* establishes connection to DB and after each test closes it.

Answer (score 0):

I had timeout too during my tests, and it was a side effect in our `Global.onStart()` function. We were trying to ensure Mongo indexes with `collection.indexesManager.ensure()`, which can be a blocking operation according to the documentation.

Since we had tests that were instantiating a new app and writing/reading into database, this indexes lead to a lot of timeout. So, one solution could be to remove any interaction with indexes when you start your application.

I know this post is quite old but hope it can help for other people.